# Activiti is not using object registered with Mocks.register() inside groovy scripts

Tags: unit-testing, groovy, mocking, jbpm, activiti

I have following problem. I try to unit test activiti flow using Mock framework provided by activiti. I have the following *activiti.cfg.xml*:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

   <bean id="processEngineConfiguration"
      class="org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.StandaloneInMemProcessEngineConfiguration">
      <property name="jobExecutorActivate" value="false" />
      <property name="expressionManager">
         <bean class="org.activiti.engine.test.mock.MockExpressionManager" />
      </property>
    </bean>
</beans>
```

Then in the test I use `ActivitiRule` to run the process:

```
@Rule
public ActivitiRule activitiRule = new ActivitiRule();

@Before
public void onInit() throws Exception {
    Mocks.reset();
    //Deploy flows ...
    Mocks.register("timeService", new TimeServiceImpl(null));
}

private void execute() {
    Map<String, Object> variables = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    variables.put("req", request);
    activitiRule.getRuntimeService().startProcessInstanceByKey("ReturningFlow", variables);
}
```

Problem that I have is that all objects registered with Mock.register() are available for use  inside ServiceTasks (inside the expression), but are not available inside groovy scripts. I get:

```
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: timeService for class: Script1
```

So the questions:
Am I doing something wrong? Is this an intended behavior of Activiti? What can I do in order to test scripts inside the flow using Mock objects?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

So after some time experimenting, I kind of hacked a solution.

We need an MockResolver for scripting objects:

```
package com.deenero.activiti;

import org.activiti.engine.delegate.VariableScope;
import org.activiti.engine.impl.scripting.Resolver;
import org.activiti.engine.impl.scripting.ResolverFactory;
import org.activiti.engine.test.mock.Mocks;

public class MockResolverFactory implements ResolverFactory{
    @Override
    public Resolver createResolver(VariableScope variableScope) {
        return new Resolver() {

            @Override
            public Object get(Object key) {
                return Mocks.get(key);
            }

            @Override
            public boolean containsKey(Object key) {
                return Mocks.get(key) != null;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

And then activiti configuration needs to be changed to use it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean id="processEngineConfiguration"
        class="org.activiti.engine.impl.cfg.StandaloneInMemProcessEngineConfiguration">
        <property name="jobExecutorActivate" value="false" />
        <property name="expressionManager">
            <bean class="org.activiti.engine.test.mock.MockExpressionManager" />
        </property>
        <property name="resolverFactories">
            <list>
                <bean class="org.activiti.engine.impl.scripting.VariableScopeResolverFactory" />
                <bean class="org.activiti.engine.impl.scripting.BeansResolverFactory" />
                <bean class="com.deenero.activiti.MockResolverFactory" />
            </list>
        </property>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

So this will allow to use all beans registered through Mock.register() inside Activiti scripts, and therefore we are able to unit test them.